# Create GeoJsonPolygon using android-maps-utils:0.5

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-datalayer, android-maps-utils

I'm using android-maps-utils:0.5 to create GeoJsonPolygon in the following way

```
private GeoJsonFeature createPolygonFeature(List<LatLng> latLngList,String id){
    GeoJsonPolygon geoJsonPolygon=new GeoJsonPolygon(Collections.singletonList(latLngList));
    return new GeoJsonFeature(geoJsonPolygon,id,null,null);
}
```

But when I'm trying to fetch the coordinates from the polygon it's returning nothing. More fact is the GeoJsonPolygon excepts `List<? extends List<LatLng>> coordinates` as a parameter which i achieved by converting my `List<LatLng> latLngList` using `Collections.singletonList(latLngList)` but I'm quite sure I'm not doing it correctly.